Is there a possible in-universe reason why lightsaber strikes don't flash-boil the victim?
It was established in official canon that lightsaber blades are NOT made of light and are instead plasma contained in a strong magnetic field. This is actually possible to do in real life and therefore it is plausible. However, because of this; a lightsaber when it cuts off a limb or makes contact with flesh; would really instantly flash-boil a persons body and then cause an explosion that would kill the wielder (most likely) as well. Is there anything in lore that could explain why this doesn’t happen?

...canon actually does not say lightsabres are plasma. They're an "energy loop" which consumes very little power to maintain when not directly cutting something. They also don't seem to generate heat unless cutting something, either.

There’s videos of plasma cutters online cutting meat. No blood flow, though, but the meat just cuts or burns. I feel like there should be a physics question about whether a plasma blade would cause a person to explode upon limb removal or whether it would just cauterise the surface of the wound (and what might contribute to either scenario). It might be blood conductivity?

Leaving open as even though real science is mentioned, the OP is looking for an in-universe answer.
